# .Net Core // Azure Active Directory // IDX20804 and IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory

We are having problems when we deploy our application to our test url. When we access the url we get an IDX20804 and IDX20803 error. (Right now our test url is http and not https. We are having problems with the certificate when we access via https)

IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'.
InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'.
[Error screen link for more information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kov0.png)

In my startup.cs,

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCustomSecurityAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
        .AddCookie();
```

If I'm not mistaken [PII is hidden] is actually a link to a metadata config document. It's linking to one of the two links below. I can access these URLs from my workstation no problem.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TenantId]/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TenantId]/.well-known/openid-configuration

My AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs,

```
private class ConfigureAzureOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
    {
        private readonly AzureAdOptions _azureOptions;
        public const string ObjectIdentifierType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier";

        public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions)
        {
            _azureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
        }

        public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
        {
            options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
            options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
            options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
            options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                //Not sure which token validation parameters to modify...
                /*
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
                */
            };

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    await TokenValidated(context, options);
                }
            };
        }
```

TokenValidated() is a separate method in that method. It's adding claims based on the current logged in user and application id. I don't think it's important for this question.

Maybe I cannot access the config document because my test url is http? And the config document is https?
Or maybe I have to modify some token validation parameters? I'm not sure which of these I need to modify.

Let me know if I need to provide any more details.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The root reason seems to be it cancels the request? Not sure why that would happen though.

Comment: I received the same error when I was trying out the new AzureADv2 endpoint, Once I used the code from here to set up authentication the problems disappeared. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/blob/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebApiStartupHelpers.cs